# SQL Server Script for deleting files from DB

Tags: sql, sql-scripts

I need to delete all rows of a table containing a bunch of files. Doing a simple `DELETE FROM` will more or less lock up the computer because of the sheer number of rows and size of files. I'm looking to create a SQL script that will accomplish this task without locking up my computer, can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you want to delete complete table use `Truncate` or do `SELECT * INTO TEMP_TABLENAME1 FROM TABLENAME1 WHERE filename <>  @fileName; Truncate Table TableName1; INSERT INTO TABLENAME1 SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLENAME1;`

Comment: @rs But will this lock up my computer just like `DELETE FROM`?

Comment: no it wont, truncate is fast and doesn't log any deletes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `TRUNCATE` - this will delete everything.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE yourTable
```

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)

> TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to the DELETE statement with no WHERE clause; however, TRUNCATE TABLE is faster and uses fewer system and transaction log resources.
>
> Compared to the DELETE statement, TRUNCATE TABLE has the following
>   advantages:
>
> Less transaction log space is used.
>
> The DELETE statement removes rows one at a time and records an entry
>   in the transaction log for each deleted row. TRUNCATE TABLE removes
>   the data by deallocating the data pages used to store the table data
>   and records only the page deallocations in the transaction log.
>
> Fewer locks are typically used.
>
> When the DELETE statement is executed using a row lock, each row in
>   the table is locked for deletion. TRUNCATE TABLE always locks the
>   table and page but not each row.
>
> Without exception, zero pages are left in the table.
>
> After a DELETE statement is executed, the table can still contain
>   empty pages. For example, empty pages in a heap cannot be deallocated
>   without at least an exclusive (LCK_M_X) table lock. If the delete
>   operation does not use a table lock, the table (heap) will contain
>   many empty pages. For indexes, the delete operation can leave empty
>   pages behind, although these pages will be deallocated quickly by a
>   background cleanup process.

Comment: Will this lock up my computer like `DELETE FROM`?

Comment: @tnw no it should not because the `TRUNCATE` does not log the row by row that `DELETE` does

Comment: ok, but what if my table has a foreign key constraint? truncate can't be used in that situation

Comment: do you have a foreign key constraint?

Comment: @tnw even delete will not work for above scenario unless you specify option to delete or leave nulls in constraint

Comment: @rs. delete has worked just fine for me in the same scenario minus the locking up, of course

Comment: @tnw truncate will not work for table with constraints, can you drop and recreate them? If you are deleting complete table i think you can drop and recreate your constraints after truncating data.